# Woocommerce, шаблон категорий не работает при наличии $_GET-параметров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В папке темы `wp-content/themes/themename/woocommerce` находится шаблон для категорий taxonomy-product_cat.php.  Он работает для категорий `/product-category/category-name`.
Но если в $_GET-параметре присутствуют значения, к примеру:
`/product-category/category-name/?param1=value`
то Wordpress ищет такие шаблоны:

- taxonomy-param1-value.php
- taxonomy-param1.php
- taxonomy.php
- archive.php
- index.php

Я так понимаю нужно добавлять новое правило для `url` с помощью `add_rewrite_rule` чтобы работал шаблон taxonomy-product_cat.php?

Comment: ещё дело в том что ` param1` это имя таксономии из плагина, получается в $_GET-параметре указана фильтрация по таксономиям